# How do I animate part of a plane getting longer over time?

Tags: animation

I would like to be able to take a plane, and animate one or more parts of it extending (getting longer over time. I include an image of what I want to happen over time.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can create this extrusion, then keep the edge selected and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object* in order to hook these vertices to an empty:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, select the empty and move it:

[image]

Comment: A thousand thanks, moonboot: it worked! If anyone is interested in how I animated the plane moving, I began by following moonboot's advice above. Then, in Object mode, I set a key frame at frame 1, choosing the "location, rotation, scale and custom properties" option. Then, still in Object mode, I moved the empty, which made the plane grow longer. Then at key frame 30, I added another key frame, choosing the "location, rotation, scale and custom properties" option again. When I played back the animation, it looks as though the plane is growing longer along one of it's edges. FABULOUS!